# How to create a simple React Dropdown

Tags: reactjs

How do you create a very, very simple dropdown select with React? Nothing seem to work.

I have an array: `var num = [1,2,3,4,5]`

**Function:**

```
num(e){
 this.setState({selected: e.target.value});
}
```

**In the render:**

```
<select option="{num}"  value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.num} />
```

No error message, no nothing. I normally use npm plugin for this but I only need something basic.

Comment: This is not a valid attribute: `option="{num}"`.  You need `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `option={num}` will not work in jsx.  You need to use `<option>` tags:

Something like this is what you are after:

```
<select name="select" onChange={this.num}>
  {num.map(function(n) { 
      return (<option value={n} selected={this.state.selected === n}>{n}</option>);
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: Ok ill try that later. Anything more simple?

Comment: @Sylar is that a joke?

Comment: @rjarmstrong I'm looking at this question in 2021 and wondering why it was even asked in the first place. Dear me!

Answer (score 4):

If you are learning React, I believe this gets to the heart of what you were asking.  Here is the JSX:

```
<select name="category" value={category} onChange={event => handleCategoryChange(event.target.value)}>
            <option id="0" >Personal</option>
            <option id="1" >Work</option>
        </select>
```

And here is the on change handler:

```
  const [category, setCategory] = React.useState('');

  const handleCategoryChange = (category) => {
     setCategory(category);
     console.log(category);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. While the first answer provided me a good basis, I just couldn't get my handler function to work properly. This `event => handleCategoryChange(event.target.value)` solved it. In my case I just had to add "event" as an argument when calling.